# Smoothing vs Regularization

Tags: smooth-manifolds, nonlinear-optimization, spline, regularization, non-convex-optimization

I am working on inverse problem - calibration of local volatility (financial application). This inverse problem is ill-posed. The optimization algorithm takes a $ \sigma $ surface as input and solves a PDE to calculate the cost function for each input. After inputs are evolved following genetic algorithm rules.
There are several authors proposing next approaches to regularize the input surface:

1. Regularization by means of Tikhonov
2. Smoothing using B-splines
3. Regularization using multiscale approach

Some authors use on of the first two approaches.
However, the author of my article uses both of them([Main Article](http://www.proba.jussieu.fr/pageperso/ramacont/papers/evolution.pdf)). For example the smoothness norm is introduced as:

$ ||\sigma||^2 = \sum_{i}^{T} \int_{-A}^{A} dx \int_{0}^{T}|\frac{d\sigma}{dT}|^2 + |\frac{d^2\sigma}{dx^2}|^2 dx$

or in matrix form:

$ ||\sigma||^2 = \theta A \theta^{T} $

where

$ \theta $ is a matrix of control points in B-Spline representation and

$ \sigma(T_{i},\cdot) = \sum_{m=1}^{M} \theta(i,m)\phi_{m}(\cdot) $

$ \sigma(t,x) = \frac{T_{i+1}-t}{T_{i+1}-T_{i}}\sigma(T_{i},x)+\frac{t-T_{i}}{T_{i+1}-T_{i}}\sigma(T_{i+1},x) $

are spline and linear interpolations by $x$ and $T$ axis respectively.
After the authors use Cholesky decomposition to obtain matrix $B$ such that $ A = BB^{T} $. 
Finally they use genetic optimization algorithm to perform random changes of control points: $ \theta_{new} = \theta + B\epsilon_{i} $.

The PDE is solved again with new candidate solutions $ \theta_{new} $ until the stopping criteria is not achieved.

Basically I do not understand the difference between regularization and smoothing.

What I do understand:

- B-Splines allow us to obtain a smooth representation of a function of interest
- Regularization is putting some convenient constraint on the function to be optimized (including the constraint of smoothness).

Isn't it enough to introduce a spline representation of the surface? (won't it be already smooth - as I understand it will).

Why do not we apply the random change directly on $ \theta $? kind of $\theta_{new} = \theta+\epsilon_{i}$

The role of smoothness norm knowing that B-Spline function is apriori smooth is not clear for me.
Thanks!